# Adding dirs to PATH for Jupyter Notebook via Anaconda virtualenv

Tags: python, linux, anaconda

I'm trying to configure Theano GPU computing for python. I'm using Anaconda and its virtualenv environment and I would like to add `/usr/local/cuda-7.5/bin` to Anaconda PATH variable. So I modified ~/.bashrc file with `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda-7.5/bin` and Anaconda bin/activate script with these same.

Now when executing the python command in Terminal: `python -c "import os; print(os.environ.get('PATH'))"`, it outputs all I want to see (Anaconda $PATH with my extra directory). But in Jupyter Notebook python, the same script outputs only Anaconda PATH without the cuda directory. I restart all kernels, clear outputs, restart anaconda, logout/login and nothing appears to work.

I'm looking for some hints to solve this problem.

Comment: do you know about all the `/etc/profile, $HOME/.profile, $HOME/.bashrc`, etc files that are processed to create your working environment? There is also probably one like `$HOME/.pythonrc`. If you're reallly lucky, `grep PATH $HOME/.*rc` will show where it is being reset as `PATH=/basic/stuff` . Good luck.